# Why password argument read as username in exec()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, exec

I tried to seed using sql file using `exec()` function in Laravel Seeder, shown below:

`exec("mysql -u ". env('DB_USERNAME') ." -p". env('DB_PASSWORD') ." ". env('DB_DATABASE') ." < " . database_path() . '/seeds/table.sql');`

But when executed `php artisan db:seed --class MySeeder`, I got this output

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '-p'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

It was always like that, no matter password argument I used (`-p` and `--password`).

But in other side, using windows with this line of code below, it works well.

`exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -u " . env('DB_USERNAME') . " --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . " < " . database_path() . '/seeds/table.sql');`

The reason I did this is because the mysql file is huge, I cannot convert or type it manual to proper seeder each rows. Can someone help me? Should I use different methods? Thank you

Details:

- Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10
- Ubuntu 18.04 on DigitalOcean
- Laravel 7
- PHP 7.3
- MySQL (php7.3-mysql + mysql_server)

Comment: you can switch the `exec()` method with an `echo()` to debug your issue.

Comment: @N69S thank you, but I found my solution by accident. Please take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so dumb, I found my solution by accident. I executed:

`composer dumpautoload`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan cache:clear`

But I guess `composer dumpautoload` was the answer. And I don't know why. If someone have perfect reason why `composer dumpautoload` solved my problem, feel free to comment :)